# TCP Client not sending data to server, Linux

Tags: java, linux, sockets, tcp

I have a Client writing in Java, it runs on Linux server. A problem occurs when client must send some data to server on different ip address. Server does not receive anything from client. Client sends on port 9000, server is listening on port 9000. I can connect to server writing: telnet ipAddress 9000 also in Linux server port 9000 is established. I use command:

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 9000 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT`
`iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 9000 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT`

What can block sending data from client on Linux server to server on different ip address? Or maybe my client code is wrong? Any ideas?

Client code:

```
public class Client extends HttpServlet implements Runnable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;  
  public void run() {
    try
    {

      @SuppressWarnings("resource")
      Socket clientSocket = new Socket("serverIpAddress", 9000);
      PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(
          new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()),true);
      pw.println("Some data to send");
      pw.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {       
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Comment: What do you have at the server end - is it another Java application? If so, can you post the code that listens for the data?

Comment: When you say "different IP address", do you mean that the two systems are possible on different networks? There's no other firewall between the two peers? What happens on the server side, do you have any logs?

Comment: Yes it is a java application, but i havent got code because i dont write it. In this program I set listening port on 9000. When i tests it on localhost with my own simple server its receive well from this client, problem is when i put client on linux server. I listening some data by wireshark and nothing received from client so I think linux blocks something.

Comment: Yes two systems have different networks. Firewall is closed os system where receive server works. On server receive side i listening wireshark program and no data receive from client.

Comment: So even Wireshark doesn't show your packets? Then there's most likely something between the two systems that drops your packets. If one system is on a corporate network, it's not uncommon for them to not allow anything beyond web-browsing.

Comment: I know what you talking about but i have forwarding set on system where receive server works and i can connected with. Some other program is sending too on other port to this server and communication is fine.

Comment: Don't use PrintWriter or PrintStream over the network. They swallow exceptions. Use BufferedWriter, then you will get an exception, then you can post it here. Edit it into your question.